# Update Firebase's branch importing Json file without creating another branch

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database in Firebase:
[image]

Every node has other nodes with locations.

I wanted to update Restaurant locations by importing a json file with total different Restaurant locations:
[image]

I decided to import this json file:

```
{
"Restaurants" : [
    {
        "l": [
            38.88449,
            -77.1060682
        ],
        "g": "dqcjjqtnd6"
    },
    {
        "l": [
            37.8649981,
            -122.245347
        ],
        "g": "9q9p6jpesg"
    }
]
}
```

My problem is when I import this new json file I want that new data locations to take the place of previous data locations, but it doesn't work like I expect because there are two nodes called `Restaurants`:

[image]

I don't know how to import json file to avoid this, what am I doing wrong?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import in the Firebase console does precisely the same thing each time, but it looks like you ran it on a different level in the data.

The first time you imported the data to the root, and it created the `Restaurants` node, since that is in the JSON file.

The second time you imported the data to the `Restaurants` node in the database, and it once again created a `Restaurants` node under that, since that is in the JSON file.

To replace the existing data, be sure to run the import on the same location in the database each time.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to update only Restaurants locations, so I need to import the data to the Restaurants node in the database, I do not understand why I have to 
import on the same location in the database each time.

Comment: The import function imports all the data from the file to the location you run the import on. The database has no way to know that you want to merge the top-level `Restaurants` node into the data that you have currently selected. The alternative is that you change your JSON file and remove the top-level node, leaving only the data under `Restaurants` (without the `Restaurants` key itself). Or you can of course write code to accomplish the same, in which case you have full control of what gets imported to where.